# Не видит listView в фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, listview, adapter, android-navigation-drawer

Подскажите в чем проблема , не видит listView, есть выпадающий список слева, в нем список оформлен через меню, в этом списке при нажатии на текст вылезает фрагмент, в этом фрагменте нужно сделать список, по которому можно будет дальше пройти на фрагмент, как можно это реализовать?

разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/honorID"
    tools:context=".NotificationsFragment">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listtime"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="445dp" />


</FrameLayout>
```

сам фрагмент

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.honor
                , null);

       list =  v.findViewById(R.id.listtime);
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Honors);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
       list.setAdapter(adapter);

      list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
        });


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.honor, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "не видит"? По коду, на первый взгляд, всё ОК

Comment: А нет, вы не ту разметку в итоге отображаете, какую настраиваете. Вам надо возвращать из onCreateView переменную `v`

Comment: что мне нужно поменять?

Comment: Заменить `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.honor, container, false);` на `return v`

Comment: спасибо, заработало, буду делать дальше, а с Вами можно как то связаться в месседжерах?

Comment: Можно, но я не вижу смысла одному человеку помогать в приватных сообщениях вместо помощи многим на доступном всем сайте.